# Load data like gmail app

Tags: android, gmail

Hello I want to download data and rotate screen like the gmail app. What is the best way to achive that?

AsyncTask,Service,Intent Service or other way?

```
public download extends AsyncTask
```

Comment: can you elaborate more ?

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate screen"? Do you mean the pull-to-refresh feature?

Comment: Change phone to landscape or portrait while downloading data

Comment: you need to create a landscape layout and a portrait layout [link]https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-layouts

Comment: Yes but the download progress will start again